# KDCircularProgressView not showing

Tags: ios, swift, uiprogressview, kdcircularprogress

I want to make `KDCircularProgressView` programmatically. I included KDCircularProgressView.swift file from https://github.com/kaandedeoglu/KDCircularProgress.

Here is code form UIViewController:

```
private var progressView: KDCircularProgress!

private func setupProgressView(){
        progressView = KDCircularProgress(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 100, height: 100))
        progressView.startAngle = 90
        progressView.angle = 90
        progressView.trackColor = UIColor.red
        progressView.progressColors = [UIColor.white]
        progressView.center = view.center

    }
```

I am calling this function in `viewDidLoad`, but nothing is showing on screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add it to main view

```
 self.view.addSubview(progressView)
```